# Update iOS Developer Program Type(Company/Organization)

Tags: ios, enterprise

hi we have an ios developer program which its type Company/Organization. Can we update our account to iOS Developer Enterprise program?

Comment: no that would mean you loose App Store rights

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple product support, not programming

Answer (score 0):

No. You can have two concurrent accounts of different types within the same company but you cannot upgrade/downgrade one to the other.